# Magento 2 - Login based controller

Tags: magento2

I need to make my controller login based, so that guest user auto redirect to login page.

And after login he/she should redirect back to that controller.

Please help me achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow below code:

```
protected $_customerSession;
protected $urlInterface;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customer,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->_customerSession = $customer;
    ...
}

public function execute()
{
    //Redirect to login page if customer is not logged in
    if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
        $this->_customerSession->authenticate();
    }
    ...
}
```

This will redirect use to login page with the current URL as referral.

This should work

Comment: Will try this..

Comment: Thanks Shoaib Munir.